# Why Jones matrix of quarter-wave plate of which fast axis is vertical is $e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-i\\\end{matrix}\right]$?

Tags: optics

Jones matrix of quarter-wave plate of which fast axis is horizontal is $e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&i\\\end{matrix}\right]$

If the plate is rotated by $π/2$, then Jones matrix is followed

$e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}&-\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}&\cos{\varphi\frac{\pi}{2}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&i\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}&\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\-\sin{\varphi\frac{\pi}{2}}&\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\\end{matrix}\right]=e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}i&0\\0&1\\\end{matrix}\right]$

Hence I think quarter-wave plate of which fast axis is vertical is $e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}i&0\\0&1\\\end{matrix}\right]$

But quarter-wave plate of which fast axis is vertical is known as $e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-i\\\end{matrix}\right]$

I don't understand why Jones matrix of quarter-wave plate of which fast axis is vertical is $e^{i\pi/4}\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-i\\\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: perhaps noticing that the difference between you results and the results given in your source is a full $-i$ factor, that is an $\exp(-i\pi/2)$ suggest a $\pi/2$ which is still vertical..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What source are you using in this derivation? Wikipedia, for example, uses the same notation as you, $e^{i\pi/4}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$, for the fast-axis vertical case and $e^{-i\pi/4}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{pmatrix}$ for the fast-axis horizontal case. Those two are compatible with your $\pi/2$ rotation condition.

Regardless, global phases are irrelevant to Jones matrix calculus, because all of the relevant physical quantities that can be measured do not depend on global phases. As such, multiplying your final Jones matrix by $-i=e^{i3\pi/2}$ does not change the physical quantity that it represents, so your final expression and your desired final expression are physically equivalent. (For example, if you would like to measure an intensity or any of the Stokes parameters, the global phase $e^{i\phi}$ and its complex conjugate $e^{-i\phi}$ will be multiplied together, yielding $1$, so the final result will never depend on the global phase.)

Comment: The source I refer is Eugene Hecht Optics 5th.

However, after reading this answer, I looked it up on the Internet, and I think you are right.
(Probably, the source has error.)

As you say, multiplying the matrix by factor results in the same as I did.

Moreover, I plot it on MATLAB to check it's right.
Although I use exp(iπ/4) for the fast-axis horizontal case, it works well as you say 'physically equivalent'

Answer (score 0):

Your rotated matrix and the wiki one are indeed equal, but you dropped a minus sign on the phase term outside of the wiki matrix. Otherwise if you factor an i out of your rotated matrix they appear to be the same.